# jQuery scroll animation to anchor even if the link redirects to another page

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, scroll, anchor

Let's say I have a page named `index.html`. Inside the document I have a link to an anchor in another page. So let's say:

```
<a href="page.html#anchor" class="scroll">Link</a>
```

Right now I have the following jQuery script to scroll with an animation to an anchor inside the same document:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

However this works if the anchor is in the same page. How can I get it to work to another page aswell? When I click the link, I want it to go to the other page and scroll to the anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your anchor to something like

```
<a href="2nd.html#anchor_temp">Go</a>
```

Because you can't prevent the default scrolling behavior of the browser

When the document is ready you need to see the hash tag value from URL then remove the _temp and then animate to it

```
$(document).ready(function(e){  
    var str= location.hash; 
    var n=str.replace("_temp","");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(n).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

I hope this will help :)

Comment: this you can use it in the 2nd page

Comment: yea I placed it in the second page

Comment: that's your link <a href="page.html#anchor" class="scroll">Link</a> ?, try to alert(location.hash);

Comment: the link is in the first, the JS is in the second. Alert works! It said #anchor

Comment: open the console FireBug or dev tools 
and what you mean by  it went directly to the anchor

Comment: It doesn't display any related error. I mean, it was supposed to scroll down the page slowly, like a transition. Instead it opens the second page immediately on the anchor position. Here, I uploaded the files for you to see www.josemelo.net/temp

Comment: try event.preventDefault(); and pass the event with the fcn

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24085/discussion-between-coldpumpkin-and-sedz)